# Django, separate settings files with a common part

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to setup Django with two separate settings files, to be selected via the command line parameter `--settings`, and that (obviously) must have a common file they both use for the common variables.

So I have the file `settings_local.py`:

```
DEBUG = True

from . import settings
```

And I expected that then in `settings` I would have been able to access `DEBUG`.

I found no way at all to do that. I've tried to use `globals()` in both files, I've tried to use `global` in both, nothing seems to work.

**Obviously** I cannot import `settings_local` *from* `settings`: the entire point of this setup is to also have a `settings_public.py` and call either one from the command line. `settings` itself should be agnostic to it.

I'm also planning to add some kind of control check to ensure `settings` is not called directly, such as:

```
try:
    DEBUG
except NameError:
    raise ValueError( "This file shouldn't be used directly." )
```

But the exception is always raised, since `DEBUG` doesn't seem to appear in `settings`.

I reiterate, even using `globals()` in both files does not work.

*Searched a lot online, couldn't find anything at all that could help me in this very specific situation. I've found many different situations, that either didn't apply, didn't work, or both.*

Answer (score 1):

Django settings are just python modules, therefore you cannot write `from . import settings` and expect `settings` to have access to global `DEBUG` variable. Just imagine importing some module which has access to all your global variables - this not only may break module code, but also can lead to bugs in your code relying to these global variables.

The correct answer depends on how complex your requirements are. If you just want to define some variables in dev / prod settings and use them in base settings file the easiest approach would be to switch to `.env` / `.ini` / any other external configuration file. E.g. with `environ` library your code may look like this:

```
# settings/base.py
import environ

env = environ.Env()
DEBUG = env.bool('DEBUG', default=False)

# now you can use DEBUG value in this file
print(DEBUG)


# settings/local.py
import os
os.environ['DEBUG'] = 'true'

from project.settings.base import *

del os.environ['DEBUG']  # del for simplicity, ideally should be restored to previous value
```

> I'm also planning to add some kind of control check to ensure settings is not called directly

I'm not sure if this is a good idea. What is the reason behind it? If you want to ensure your settings variables are not conflicting with each other it will be better to check their values, without relying on whether the settings module was imported directly or through prod / dev settings. This **can** be implemented, if you really want to, you'll just need some flag which will indicate if someone imported your base settings outside of dev / prod settings. But this looks like an unnecessary complexity added to the settings module, which should be as simple and dumb as possible

Comment: This is interesting, thank you, I'll try and let you know.